# C++ making and destroying unique_ptr pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am learning ways to use pointer with `std::unique_ptr`.
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class object{
public:
    void say(){
            std::cout<<"hi";
    }
};

int main(){
      std::unique_ptr<object> p = 
                  std::unique_ptr<object>(new object);
      p->say();
}
```

My questions are:

1. Am I using `std::unique_ptr` correctly?
2. How can I delete or remove this (`p`) pointer, so there is no memory usage or leak?

Comment: I have to say that no, you are not using it correctly since there is no reason to declare the object on the heap anyway. declaring variables in the right place solves about 50% of the leaks out there.

Comment: @DavidHaim: You deleted your answer, so I couldn't respond to your request for a standard reference, but it's 5.3.4/20 in N3797

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<object> p = std::unique_ptr<object>(new object);
```

This is fine, but you could simplify this like so:

```
std::unique_ptr<object> p { new object{} };
```

Or like this in C++14:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<object>();
```

You don't need to `delete` a `std::unique_ptr`, that's the whole point. When `p` goes out of scope (at the end of `main`), the pointee will be `delete`d automatically.

That said, there's no need to use dynamic allocation in this example. You should just use an automatic variable instead:

```
int main(){
      object p{};
      p.say();
}
```

A good rule of thumb is to use automatic storage duration when you can and dynamic storage duration when you must.

---

`std::make_unique` has the advantage of protecting against leaks in situations like this:

```
process(std::unique_ptr<object>(new object), iMightThrow());
```

If `new object` is executed first, then `iMightThrow` runs and throws, memory will be leaked. `std::make_unique` guards against this:

```
process(std::make_unique<object>(), iMightThrow());
```

Now if `iMightThrow()` throws, the `std::unique_ptr` will either not have been created, or it will be destroyed and reclaim the memory.

Answer (score 2):

`std::unique_ptr<object> p(new object);` is enough.
You don't have to do anything with it, after it goes out of scope it destroys the object.

Comment: it's not enough. if object throws an exception there will be a memory leak, `make_unique` is the only way  without using placement new.

Comment: @DavidHaim How would memory be leaked in this case? I think you're thinking of something like `process(std::unique_ptr<object>(new object), iMightThrow());`

Comment: @DavidHaim can you stop repeating that rubbish?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are using it the right way. However, if C++ 14 is available you may create it like this:

```cpp
auto p = std::make_unique<object>();
```

About deleting it. It does not need to be deleted. This is the idea of smart pointers in general. It will delete the memory that it was allocated by itself when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you are not using the `unique_ptr` in a bad way.  `unique_ptr` uses the *Resource Acquisition Is Initialization* paradigm - i.e. managing the **new Object** is a unique_ptr's responsibility.
2. This means that you don't have to explicitly delete the pointer `p`, because when the `unique_ptr` goes out of scope (end of the block, or function in this case) its destructor will manage to free the memory in the correct way without causing any leak.

Look at the following code (that works similarly to `unique_ptr`):

```
template<class T>
class ScopedPointer : NonCopiable{
private:
    T * pointer;
public:
     ScopedPointer( T  *p): pointer(p){};

    virtual ~ScopedPointer(){

            delete pointer;
    };
    T * operator->() const {return pointer;};
    T & operator*() const {return *pointer;};

};
```

The `ScopedPointer` destructor will take care of deleting the raw pointer!

Answer (score 0):

if you can use C++ 14 you can have a short hand:

```
auto p = std::make_unique<object>();
```

There is no memory leak here, the unique_ptr wraps the heap allocation and when it goes out of scope it releases the resource. You don't need to release it manually, just use it as a normal variable, just be careful of it s scope of course.

Comment: yes you are right, I was just double checking it, thanks for the heads up I fixed it

Comment: ps you can manually release a unique_ptr resource using
unique_ptr.reset()